# Is there a way to write a dynamic actionlistener for an array of ComboBoxes

Tags: java, arrays, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

I'm working on a database management system GUI that creates comboboxes dynamically based on the number of teams competing directly; if there are two teams it creates two comboboxes, three teams it creates three boxes, so on and so forth.  Inside of the forloop that initializes and places the comboboxes I add an ActionListener to each of them. Within my nested class that implements ActionListener I have a series of if, else if statements that checks to see the source of the Action.  Do I need to create a separate check for each possible instance, or is there a way to make it more dynamic?  Basically I want to populate the first combobox with a list of options, once an option has been selected I want it to be removed from the list of options for subsequent comboboxes.

```
else if(e.getSource()==TournamentMatchupCreatebtn)
            {
                String[] MatchCreationOptions = {"Create Match","Cancel"};
                JPanel MatchCreationpnl = new JPanel();
                MatchCreationpnl.setLayout(null);
                Object[] NumofTeamsARGS = {TournamentRestbl.getValueAt(TournamentRestbl.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString()};
                int NumofTeams = Integer.parseInt(dbUpdater.getData(TournamentMatchupHDR,TeamCountqry, NumofTeamsARGS).getValueAt(0, 0).toString());
                System.out.println(NumofTeams);
                String LabelFlag = dbUpdater.getData(MatchTypeHDR,MatchTypeqry,NumofTeamsARGS).getValueAt(0, 0).toString();
                System.out.println(LabelFlag);
                String LabelText;
                if(LabelFlag.equals("Teams"))
                {
                    LabelText = "Team:";
                }
                else
                {
                    LabelText = "Player:";
                }
                 ArrayList<String> PlayersList = new ArrayList<String>();
                DefaultComboBoxModel dcmb = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
                dcmb = dbUpdater.getSpecificValues(MatchTypeqry, NumofTeamsARGS);
                for(int i = 0; i<dcmb.getSize();i++)
                {
                    PlayersList.add(dcmb.getElementAt(i).toString());
                }
                JLabel[] TeamPlayerlbl = new JLabel[NumofTeams];
                TeamPlayercmbx = new JComboBox[NumofTeams];
                JLabel[] VSlbl = new JLabel[NumofTeams];
                for(int i = 0;i<NumofTeams;i++)
                {
                    TeamPlayerlbl[i] = new JLabel(LabelText);
                    if(i==0)
                    {
                    TeamPlayercmbx[i] = new JComboBox(PlayersList.toArray());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TeamPlayercmbx[i]= new JComboBox();
                    }

                    VSlbl[i] = new JLabel("VS");
                    TeamPlayerlbl[i].setSize(TeamPlayerlbl[i].getPreferredSize());
                    addComponent(MatchCreationpnl,TeamPlayerlbl[i], 5,i*50+5);
                    addComponent(MatchCreationpnl,TeamPlayercmbx[i],TeamPlayerlbl[i],i*50+5,150,20,5);
                    VSlbl[i].setSize(VSlbl[i].getPreferredSize());
                    if(i<NumofTeams-1)
                    {
                    addComponent(MatchCreationpnl,VSlbl[i],100,i*50+30);
                    }
                    TeamPlayercmbx[i].setEditable(false);
                    TeamPlayercmbx[i].addActionListener(action);
                }
                TeamPlayercmbx[0].setEditable(true);
                TeamPlayercmbx[0].setModel(MatchTypes);

                MatchCreationpnl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,NumofTeams*50+5));
                int x = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,MatchCreationpnl,"Create Tournament Match", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,null,MatchCreationOptions,null);
            }
```

That code creates the interface for creating a match, I know I shouldn't be setting pixel specific locations for these things, in the next version I make I'll work on making the interface more flexible to fit the screen it's being displayed on.

```
else if(e.getSource()==TeamPlayercmbx[0])
            {
               ArrayList <String> Competitors = new ArrayList();
               for(int i=0;i<TeamPlayercmbx[0].getItemCount();i++)
               {
                   Competitors.add(TeamPlayercmbx[0].getItemAt(i).toString());
               }
               DefaultComboBoxModel DCMB = new DefaultComboBoxModel(Competitors.toArray());
               TeamPlayercmbx[1].setEditable(true);
               TeamPlayercmbx[1].setModel(DCMB);
               TeamPlayercmbx[1].removeItem(TeamPlayercmbx[0].getSelectedItem());
            }
```

That code removes the selected item from the model and allows you to select a value for the second combobox.  What I need to know is if there's a way to replace

```
else if(e.getSource()==TeamPlayercmbx[0]
```

with something along the lines of

```
else if(e.getSource()==TeamPlayercmbx[some variable]
```

or if I need to just hard code this out

Comment: I think I've come up with a simple solution using a for loop.  I'll test it once I get home and if it works I'll post the code as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve this on my own using a simple for loop:

```
for(int x =0;x<TeamPlayercmbx.length;x++)
{
      if(e.getSource()==TeamPlayercmbx[x])
      {
            try
            {
                 ArrayList <String> Competitors = new ArrayList();
                 for(int i=0;i<TeamPlayercmbx[x].getItemCount();i++)
                 {               
                       Competitors.add(TeamPlayercmbx[x].getItemAt(i).toString());
                 }
                 DefaultComboBoxModel DCMB = new 
                 DefaultComboBoxModel(Competitors.toArray());
                 TeamPlayercmbx[x+1].setEditable(true);
                 TeamPlayercmbx[x+1].setModel(DCMB);
                 TeamPlayercmbx[x+1].removeItem(TeamPlayercmbx[x].getSelectedItem());
                 }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
            }
     }
}
```

It seems pretty obvious after the fact.  Hopefully the answer helps someone else though.